# json parsing error with same json using jquery.parsejson

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

i have the same json string twice but the second time i get an error.

```
{"data":[{"ServerID":"1","UserID":"3","Name":"salzig","State_since":"2012-11-23T23:16:27.458000000","State":"saved","UUID":"Hardware   85f5d278-f6d6-49c2-87e7-c249d8002897"}],"error":[null,null,null]} devcontrol.js:8

{"data":[{"ServerID":"1","UserID":"3","Name":"salzig","State_since":"2012-11-23T23:16:27.458000000","State":"saved","UUID":"Hardware   85f5d278-f6d6-49c2-87e7-c249d8002897"}],"error":[null,null,null]} devcontrol.js:8
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON' devcontrol.js:9

my code line devcontrol.js 8 and 9:

```
console.log(data);
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

how can that be.

**update**
i now made a console.log($) evry trime bevor he trys to convert the string into a json and got

```
undefined
```

it turnd out the secounde time it's undefined.
i managed to found out it was because of zfdebug they used document ready and then asked about jquery noconfilect thats why $ was undifend the secound time

Comment: Are you using any other libraries that use `$` as a variable? What happens when you try `jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: show more code where the json comes from. Is `data` an object or a string?

Comment: @charlietfl - What's the difference?

Comment: You're going to need to give more information about what's going on in your code, because obviously there isn't just a bug in jQuery where it can't parse that string twice.

Comment: @Aesthete  read the docs. **`Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.`**  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @charlietfl - Read the question - the object **has no method `parseJSON`**. Who cares what the argument is if the method doesn't even exist?

Comment: @Aesthete  ... yup, good point, I got sidetracked. I had already +1 on your `$` comment.

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks. Since the OP hasn't replied to my question, I'm just going to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Aesthete  ... might be loading sequence also

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON' devcontrol.js:9
```

Is telling you that the object you're referencing with the `$` variable has no method called that. This could be caused by a few things.

- You're using an old version that doesn't support this function. `parseJSON` was introduced in **version 1.4.1**. Either update your version, or use the native `JSON.parse()` method.
- Your script link to `jQuery` is wrong. Checked the page loaded the source script with a `200 success`
- Another library is taking the `$` variable *after* jquery has defined it. You can disassociate jQuery from the `$` variable using `jQuery.noConflict()`, reassign to anothe variable like `$$`, or just using `jQuery.parseJSON()`
- You have scripts running before the page is fully loaded. Make sure every is run within `$(document).ready(function () { /*your code here*/ });`

Comment: also make sure jQuery loaded before any jQuery dependent code